# iOS: Sort files in a folder according to the order of an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, path, nsfilemanager, nssortdescriptor

I have a folder that contain files B, C, A.  This is the order they appear in when I do the following:

```
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSArray *filelist;
    int count;
    int i;

    filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPathHere error:NULL];
    count = [filelist count];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

       NSLog(@"File %@ is at index: %d", [filelist objectAtIndex: i], i);

    }
```

How can I sort the files so they match the order of an array of strings, for example A, B, C ?

Should I use `sortUsingDescriptors`?

Comment: Do you really need to sort the files in that folder or is sorting the filelist array sufficient?

Comment: I need to sort them @HermannKlecker.

Comment: Well, I asked "A or B" and your answer ist "YES".

Comment: Fair enough! A - I need to sort the files in that folder

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try - Traverse the paths as NSURLs and use the `NSURLLocalizedNameKey` property:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:oneDir.path]
                        includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject: NSURLFileResourceIdentifierKey]
                                           options:nil
                                             error:nil];

for (NSURL *f in fileList) {
    NSString *name = nil;
    if ([f getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stavesh.  Thanks for suggestion.  I tried this code replacing `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]` with `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:oneDir.path]` where my path to the folder is oneDir.path and `NSURLLocalizedNameKey` with my Array but it didn't do anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't do anything == same exact order?

Comment: Is this the correct code for the line:  `NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:oneDir.path]
                               includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.forEachSalesCallAnArrayWithIndicesOfThumbnailsKeys]
                                                  options:nil
                                                    error:nil];` ?

Comment: Above, my array is `self.forEachSalesCallAnArrayWithIndicesOfThumbnailsKeys` and my path is `oneDir.path`

Comment: No, just the oneDir.path part should be replaced. The other array is an array of property keys that are used to determine the order of traversal

Comment: OK, cool.  So how do I get the order to match my array?  Sorry for the ignorance, it's been a very long day

Comment: The given example order 'A, B, C' was an example, actual order could be anything and is determined at run time.  I therefore want it to match an array

Comment: Anyway, thanks I will check out any updated answer(s) tomorrow

Comment: Sorry, so I misunderstood your question. You might want to try NSURLFileResourceIdentifierKey instead of NSURLLocalizedNameKey. Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Common_File_System_Resource_Keys for a better idea of what I'm going for here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean in the order of a list of characters (single character strings), but this could be more complex too:

- construct an inclusive array of strings (characters). If you will have "Ca" and "C", then the former has to be first.
- create a dictionary with the strings, the string is the key and use a NSNumber representing its order in the array as the object.
- create a separate dictionary that given a prefix letter string, returns the longest possible match needed to insure that each key in the first dictionary is found

Now, when you get a list of files:

- use the first character of the file name as the key to get the maximum number of characters to use in searching in the first.
- get those characters, and look for a match in the first dictionary. If not found, reduce the string length one by one til you get a match. Now you know the order for this file name. Add it to a new dictionary with the file name as the key and a NSNumber representing its order as the object.
- get the array of all values from this new dictionary, and sort it based on the value of the NSNumber. There will be duplicates that you need to discard.
- repetively get the dictionary objects that have the specified value. You may want to further sort based on some other criteria

So, you could decide you want file names starting with vowels first, then other chars. So your first array is "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "B", ...

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I'll check it out in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

This should be array of strings so sort the strings

```
NSArray * sortedStrings = [filelist sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I'll check it out in the morning but I think this just sorts the array, NOT sorts the files on disk